# Switch code R with different if statements

Tags: r, if-statement, switch-statement

So I'm trying to wrap my head around the switch function because I think it is the one I need. Essentially I have a dataset that needs to be sorted based on different criteria.

So if Case 1 = 1

I have a set of code and if statements that would do something with the data set

Then if Case 1 = 0,

then there are a set of different combinations the user can choose (1 use this data, 0 don't use):

```
Use_A = 0/1 
Use_B = 0/1
Use_C = 0/1
Use_D = 0/1
```

and then based on which USES the are selected, there's a set of if statements that would happen.

I believe the switch function is what would be used, but I'm not 100% sure how to do about this. The end result of any case will be a new data frame

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code and the expected output?

Comment: This may be easier than trying to write everything out: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_switch_statement.htm

Comment: A better approach would be dplyr's `case_when`, which doesn't limit you to integer cases.

Comment: What criteria are you using and what sort of things are you sorting by? Jens posted a good link about switch statements, but often in R there are other ways to call commands without if or case.

Comment: it's an integrated data set from 4 different projects. So depending on which project the user selects, it will combine the data frame in a way that is specific to those projects into a new data frame. So if someone inputs that A = 1, B =1, C = 0, D=0 then they only want data from projects A and B, so C and D need to be tosed and then A and B need to be organized in certain way. if that makes any sense?

Comment: If you're wondering how to write a function for this, maybe use two arguments and `match.arg` like `f = function(case1 = TRUE, dsets = LETTERS[1:4]){if (case1){"ha"} else {dsets = match.arg(dsets, several.ok = TRUE); dsets}}` where you fill in the `{}` with whatever you want to happen in those cases.

Comment: I second Frank's suggestion:  nested if...else statements sound like what you might be in search of - see here for another example: https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/if-else-statement